# How do Xamarin developers create native libraries to C#?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How do Xamarin developers create native libraries to C#?

I can see The have lot of Google service libraries ex: `Xamarin.Firebase.Auth`. I'm a java and Kotlin developer I wanted to use the Kotlin code (module) from Android studio to Xamarin.Android. I have followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-kotlin-library/walkthrough) and I build an .aar without dependencies and import to Xamarin android successfully. But the problem is with Gradle dependencies like `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'` , `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` I get errors:

```
{Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.companyname.mylibrary.Authenticate$auth$callbacks$1
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <26521a5118b44c858c385715922b9d5d>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0001f] in <26521a5118b44c858c385715922b9d5d>:0 
  at Com.Companyname.Mylibrary.Authenticate.Auth () [0x00002] in C:\Users\duval\source\repos\LibraryTest\ClassLibrary1\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Companyname.Mylibrary.Authenticate.cs:72 
  at LibraryTest.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00042] in C:\Users\duval\source\repos\LibraryTest\LibraryTest\LibraryTest.Android\MainActivity.cs:27 
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <4ccdb3137d974856b786e1aeebbfbab6>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.8(intptr,intptr,intptr)
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError stack trace ---
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.companyname.mylibrary.Authenticate$auth$callbacks$1
    at com.companyname.mylibrary.Authenticate.auth(Authenticate.kt:15)
    at crc641e1c496b96c0654c.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at crc641e1c496b96c0654c.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
}
```

How do they do to make sure to import also the dependencies?

In my application graddle I have the Google dependency:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' //The dependency

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

In my module graddle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // the Google plugin

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1' // The firebase auth
}
```

The module single class:

```
import android.util.Log
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class Authenticate(private val activity: Activity) {

    val TAG = "COM.Authenticate"

    fun auth(){
        val callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:$credential")
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e)
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(
                verificationId: String,
                token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
            ) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:$verificationId")
            }
        }

        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            "+16505559999", // Phone number to verify
            60, // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Unit of timeout
            activity, // Activity (for callback binding)
            callbacks) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    }
}
```

Calling it inside an activity:

```
Authenticate authenticate = new Authenticate(this);
authenticate.Auth();
```

**Edited**

I just create a new empty android studio project and import my aar library (`File -> new -> new module -> Import .jar/.aar package`), in the app module graddle I set `implementation project(":my-library-name")`.

And when I run the application I got this error when calling the library:

```
2020-05-05 16:11:36.626 11752-11752/com.companyname.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.companyname.myapplication, PID: 11752
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider$OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks;
        at com.companyname.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider$OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.myapplication-b6SAtovKWrC0PkwlBsVC8w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.myapplication-b6SAtovKWrC0PkwlBsVC8w==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.companyname.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:13) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2020-05-05 16:11:36.643 11752-11752/com.companyname.myapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11752 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Have you added **google-services.json** and initialized the Firebase before calling FirebaseAuth.GetInstance?

Comment: Yes. The problem with the `Xamarin.Firebase.Auth` is now solved. But I want to be able to import `.aar` libraries with graddle dependencies into Xamarin android (Bindable link library).

Comment: So what is the error shown? can you update your question to show relevant error

Comment: @Prateek I updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: still the error is not clear. you added only 1 line of error, no log. its hard to tell. What happens if you pack aars with google-services intact. Have you tried adding Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.* nugets?

Comment: I updated the question to add the entire exception log. What do you mean by `pack aars with google-services intact`? Yes, the Google play services are available in the nuget packages. But the point is not to use the nuget packages. Instead is about using graddle or android packages in the module.

Comment: Nuget are wrapper around native jar/aar files, there is no gradle linking in Xamarin.  Error seems to be from incorrect binding library creation. and not due to google services dependency.  *I have followed this tutorial and I build an .aar without dependencies* -> I mean have you tried to build aar with these dependencies which are causing issue you think? You can open up aar file in any zip(7zip/winrar) software and inspect the classes(probably have to decompile) and check methods are there or not. I belive they are not.

Comment: and the wrapper converter wont create methods or classes if the classes dont have the dependent classes/pkgs in available, perhaps you removed them. `com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential` `com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider` and `com.google.firebase.FirebaseException` should be present in aar

Comment: The question is how to make sure those dependent classes are included in the aar? You can see my graddle script for the project and the module. Now what's missing?

Comment: gradle script downloads and creates pkgs , those have to be a part of building aar.

Comment: @Prateek sorry for the late. I just from graddle menu `my-library -> Tasks -> built -> assemble` then import the aar file generated.

Comment: I also edited the question to add new information.